# Android: get time difference in seconds between two timezones

Tags: android

I am new to Android.

How can I get the difference between two timezones in seconds in Android?

For example the difference between Asia/Tehran(+4:30) and Asia/Baghdad(+3:00) is 5400 sec (1:30 hour).

Comment: It's basic math. (Hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60) = total seconds. The math is the same in any language, on paper, or using a calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved:

```
int loc2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran").getRawOffset();
int loc1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC").getRawOffset();
return (loc2 - loc1) / 1000;
```

To calculate more accurately(with summer day light time):

```
public int getTimezoneDifferenceInSecond(String zone1, String zone2) {
    Date now = new Date();
    TimeZone timeZone1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zone1);
    TimeZone timeZone2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zone2);

    int currentOffsetFromUTC = timeZone1.getRawOffset() + (timeZone1.inDaylightTime(now) ? timeZone1.getDSTSavings() : 0);
    int serverOffsetFromUTC = timeZone2.getRawOffset() + (timeZone2.inDaylightTime(now) ? timeZone2.getDSTSavings() : 0);
    return (serverOffsetFromUTC - currentOffsetFromUTC) / 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

//you should now have timezone calculated in miliseconds
df1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("<timezone_you_want>"));
df2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("<timezone_you_want>"));

//do the difference and calculate hours
long diffInMillisec = df1 - df2;
long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMillisec);
```

Comment: Did you declare also df2 same way as df1 ?

Comment: yes, error is: Error: bad operand types for binary operator '-'
first type:  DateFormat, 
second type: DateFormat